# Why instanceof returns success in this scenario

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, instanceof

I was trying to understand why I am getting those results (which not why I expected)"

```
public interface ICommandAble
{ }

public interface ILogAble extends ICommandAble
{ }

public interface IMonitorAble extends ICommandAble
{ }

public abstract class ClassAbs
{ }

public class A extends ClassAbs implements IMonitorAble, ILogAble
{ }
```

**Test method:**

```
public void test()
{
   A a=new A();
   List<ICommandAble>commandList=new ArrayList<ICommandAble>()
   if (a instanceof ILogAble)
   {
       ILogAble logAbleItem=(ILogAble)a;
       commandList.add(logAbleItem);
   }
   if (a instanceof IMonitorAble) {
       IMonitorAble monitorAbleItem=(IMonitorAble)a;
       commandList.add(monitorAbleItem);
   }
   for(ICommandAble item: commandList)
   {
        if(item instanceof IMonitorAble)
        {
          log.debug("is monitorable");
        }
        if(item instanceof ILogAble)
        {
          log.debug("is logable");
        }
}
```

the output is:

> 2013-04-22 18:25:00,498 com... [DEBUG] is monitorable
>
> 2013-04-22 18:25:02,150 com.... [DEBUG] is logable
>
> 2013-04-22 18:25:08,322 com.... [DEBUG] is monitorable
>
> 2013-04-22 18:25:08,977 com.... [DEBUG] is logable
>
> I expected to see:.
>
> 2013-04-22 18:25:00,498 com... [DEBUG] is monitorable
>
> 2013-04-22 18:25:02,150 com.... [DEBUG] is logable

What am I missing here?

I understand now what I miss here. But how should I redesign this that it will enter in the second instance-of only once? My intent was to see this:

```
2013-04-22 18:25:00,498 com... [DEBUG] is monitorable

2013-04-22 18:25:02,150 com.... [DEBUG] is logable
```

Any recommendations for re-design this?

Else I will get the double execution of everything while my intent was to have only a single execution of each one.

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: If either condition is true (`a instanceof x || a instance of y`), add the object to your list.  You shouldn't need to cast it, other than to an ICommandAble in scenarios where the incoming value isn't known to the compiler to be a subclass of ICommandAble.

Comment: Or use a variety of list that eliminates duplicates.

Comment: It's not a good solution for me if either of the condition is true.  its sounds like a dirty workaround. what if I have more objects like "xAble" and "yAble" that's going to look really bad.

Comment: If you have a whole bunch and want separate if statements for each, just have your if statements set a boolean flag if the object should be included.  Test the boolean at the end.

Comment: And, of course, if all you want is to know if the object is a subclass of ICommandAble, just do `a instanceof ICommandAble`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've added two objects of class `A`. `A` is both monitorable and loggable so the output is correct.

*What am I missing here?* :- Casting an object does not change its type.

Comment: @rayman - You asked a question - I answered it. If you would like to ask another one please do so in a separate question.

Comment: You right. I created new one at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156241/redesign-the-oop-avoiding-duplicate-executions

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a object of the class A. And this is an instance of IMonitorAble and ILogAble. By casting it to one of the interfaces it still is an object of A.
So you have the same object twice in your List and both if statements int your for loop are true for this object.