# Redesign the OOP Splitting combined interfaces to individuals

Tags: java, oop, architecture, polymorphism

I was trying to understand how to avoid double entry in a clean and "designable" way to the following scenario:

```
public interface ICommandAble
{ }

public interface ILogAble extends ICommandAble
{ }

public interface IMonitorAble extends ICommandAble
{ }

public abstract class ClassAbs
{ }

public class A extends ClassAbs implements IMonitorAble, ILogAble
{ }
```

**Test method:**

```
public void test()
{
   A a=new A();
   List<ICommandAble>commandList=new ArrayList<ICommandAble>()
   if (a instanceof ILogAble)
   {
       ILogAble logAbleItem=(ILogAble)a;
       commandList.add(logAbleItem);
   }
   if (a instanceof IMonitorAble) {
       IMonitorAble monitorAbleItem=(IMonitorAble)a;
       commandList.add(monitorAbleItem);
   }
   for(ICommandAble item: commandList)
   {
        if(item instanceof IMonitorAble)
        {
          log.debug("is monitorable");
        }
        if(item instanceof ILogAble)
        {
          log.debug("is logable");
        }
}
```

the output is:

> 2013-04-22 18:25:00,498 com... [DEBUG] is monitorable
>
> 2013-04-22 18:25:02,150 com.... [DEBUG] is logable
>
> 2013-04-22 18:25:08,322 com.... [DEBUG] is monitorable
>
> 2013-04-22 18:25:08,977 com.... [DEBUG] is logable

That will cause my program to do double executions for each "xAble"

I expected to see:

> 2013-04-22 18:25:00,498 com... [DEBUG] is monitorable
>
> 2013-04-22 18:25:02,150 com.... [DEBUG] is logable

How should I redesign this(in a clean way) that the second iterator conditionion will be based on the reference type and not on the instance type. getting something like this:

```
2013-04-22 18:25:00,498 com... [DEBUG] is monitorable

2013-04-22 18:25:02,150 com.... [DEBUG] is logable
```

- Think that in the future I might have additional "ables"

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing objects to see if they are instances of interfaces then they must implement that interface. They can always implement other interfaces too. In your scenario, to achieve the output you need you must make the objects only implement one of the two interfaces.

```
public class Test {
  public interface ICommandAble {
  }

  public interface ILogAble extends ICommandAble {
  }

  public interface IMonitorAble extends ICommandAble {
  }

  public abstract class ClassAbs {
  }

  public class A extends ClassAbs implements IMonitorAble, ILogAble {
  }

  public class B extends ClassAbs implements IMonitorAble {
  }

  public class C extends ClassAbs implements ILogAble {
  }

  public void test() {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();
    List<ICommandAble> commandList = new ArrayList<ICommandAble>();
    commandList.add(a); // Remove this line to just get the two printouts.
    commandList.add(b);
    commandList.add(c);
    for (ICommandAble item : commandList) {
      if (item instanceof IMonitorAble) {
        System.out.println(item.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is monitorable");
      }
      if (item instanceof ILogAble) {
        System.out.println(item.getClass().getSimpleName() + " is logable");
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test().test();
  }
}
```

prints

```
A is monitorable
A is logable
B is monitorable
C is logable
```

I have added an `A` to the list too to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: I cant remove line A. this object exists. thats the whole point that I have an object that implements both interfaces but I need it to be executed only once per interface. each object has it's own data.

Comment: But I did casting - ILogAble logAbleItem=(ILogAble)a; so why it's still returning true for the other condition? (MonitorAble)

Comment: @rayman - As I pointed out in my other answer, casting **does not affect the object** in any way. `instanceof` tests the original object, not the type you have casted it to.

Comment: @rayman - If you want each object only to be processed once then use an `else if` between your tests.

Comment: But that wont be good for me.. because I want object to be handled as monitorable and logable.. but only once. in other words I need my condition to be based somehow on the reference type and not on the instance type. how I do that?

Comment: @rayman - Then you need to decide exactly what should happen to objects that are **both** monitorable **and** loggable and code that. There is no way around - either treat it as `a || b` or have a special case for `a && b` or decide for yourself some special logic. Attempting to cast the objects clearly will not work. If the decision should be made when the object is posted than it should be an `attribute` of the object, not derived from the `class` of the object.

Comment: My architecture works that way that via the interface a different business logic will occurs to a concrete object. so if objects implements multiple interfaces multiple bushines logic will be triggered. that why the code will be very clean and "interfaceable"

Comment: This does not get you anywhere. You need to decide **exactly** what you want to happen if an object implements multiple interfaces. Should it be processed twice (once for each interface) or once (for a primary interface perhaps). If you only know at the time it is added to the list you could consider using two lists.

Comment: I know exactly what I want to happen when object implements multiple interfaces.. it will be handled differently for each one. thats why I made the second instanceof problem is that I cant "SPLIT" it to individuals which causing me duplications. I thought having diffrent commands list for each interface but that's just an extra maintenance when new interfaces will come in the future. I tried to think about better way in order to minimize maintenance when new interfaces will come along.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28720/discussion-between-rayman-and-oldcurmudgeon)

Answer (score 0):

As you are only adding items to an `List`, you can change your code to verify if it is an instance of `ICommandAble`, like this:

```
if (a instanceof ICommandAble) {
   commandList.add(a);
}
```

Comment: I edited the answer because this new approach fits better with the code given.

Comment: Not sure I understand you? how does it help ?

Comment: You want to add objects to a `List` and check which interfaces they implement after that. In your oiginal code you make a verification to see if `a` is an instance of one of your interfaces. The problem is when you have an object implementing more than one interface: it is added more than once to the `List`. To fix it, just check if `a` is an instance of `ICommandAbble` and you can add as much "ables" in the future as you think is necessary that it will still add only one instance regardless of how many interfaces it implements.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your adding `a` into the commandList twice, once for being loggable and again for being monitorable.

You should combine the 2 if statements into 1:

```
if (a instanceof ILogAble || a instanceof IMonitorAble)
{
    commandList.add(a);
}
```

Comment: Yes but if ill have more "xAble" interfaces thats gonna be huge and dirty solution dont you think?

Answer (score 0):

Add the instances to a hashset not a list so that an instance would be present once even if it added more than once

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers already explained, what you want is not possible with casting. You will need to use multiple lists. You can organize this lists in a Map to make it more maintainable, but maybe you should rethink your design.

Here a way how you could easily use multiple lists:

```
public interface ICommandAble {}

public interface ILogAble extends ICommandAble {}

public interface IMonitorAble extends ICommandAble {}

public abstract class ClassAbs {}

public class A extends ClassAbs implements IMonitorAble, ILogAble {}

public List<ICommandAble> getList(LinkedHashMap<Class<? extends ICommandAble>, List<ICommandAble>> commandList,
        Class<? extends ICommandAble> clazz) {
    if (commandList.get(clazz) != null)
        return commandList.get(clazz);
    ArrayList<ICommandAble> l = new ArrayList<>();
    commandList.put(clazz, l);
    return l;
}

public void test() {
    A a = new A();
    LinkedHashMap<Class<? extends ICommandAble>, List<ICommandAble>> commandList = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    if (a instanceof ILogAble)
        getList(commandList, ILogAble.class).add(a);

    if (a instanceof IMonitorAble)
        getList(commandList, IMonitorAble.class).add(a);

    for (Class<? extends ICommandAble> clazz : commandList.keySet())
        for (ICommandAble item : commandList.get(clazz)) {
            if (clazz.equals(IMonitorAble.class))
                log("is monitorable");
            if (clazz.equals(ILogAble.class))
                log("is logable");
        }
}
```

Comment: I guess it works with lists. But maybe you have another suggestion for redesignig ?